# How can I add line space between WordPress Title?

Tags: css, wordpress

Actually whenever there are two lines in title, it gets very close, which makes it hard to read. So can anyone tell custom CSS that I add for space in between H1 tag in Tittle?

Comment: Use `line-height` property

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Please make a working fiddle, or post full HTML and CSS code

Comment: cannot post the full CSS, it shows limit.

Comment: https://demo.themegrill.com/colornews/2015/07/23/use-of-computer-increases-to-keep-the-record/

Comment: this is the theme

Comment: can you please specify which title you talk about on this template.

Comment: Ok, Checked, Wait I update my answer

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: finally it worked, I copied the code in additional CSS option. Anyways it was really hard to get it right. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I appreciate your patience, If my answer is right, then please vote up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your H1 tag in your css to have a larger line height

```
h1 { line-height: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `line-height`

```css
.page-title {
   line-height: 40px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page-title">Very Very Very Very Very Long Long Long Long Page Title</h1>
```

Comment: Can you provided code or any working link? So that i can check it

Comment: Posts and pages
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

h1.entry-title,
h2.entry-title {
 color: #353535;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font-size: 36px;
}

h1.entry-title a {
 color: #3d3d3d;
}

Comment: Try this: `h1.entry-title {line-height: 45px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the line height should fix that

```
h1 {
 line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Comment: Where to adjust it...I mean shall I simply add the code in custom CSS option or I need to make changes in style.css

Comment: Adding to custom css should be enough, but that will effect all H1 in the website

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with padding. Padding basically let's you put in some extra pixels in the wanted direction. So for instance: for your title to stay in position on your screen, add 5 px of padding-bottom.

looks like this

```
padding-bottom: 5px;
```

...or whatever amount of space you want in there but this is basically how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your template [Link](https://demo.themegrill.com/colornews/2015/07/23/use-of-computer-increases-to-keep-the-record/) you provide at comment, You are talking about this line,
"Use Of Computer Increases To Keep The Record"

#### Solution:

First open style.css, then got to line 2535 or find,

```
article.post.hentry h1.entry-title, article.post.hentry h2.entry-title {
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
```

Increase `line-height` property 26 to 36 `line-height: 36px;`.(increase as it looks goods to you)

This was before
[image: Before]

This is after
[image]

It's worked for me, Let's take another try,

Try using this `line-height: 36px!important;`

Comment: Its so confusing :/